# NSDate sorting in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to sort my array of Event Object (custom class), I am getting following error. Any idea.

[image: Sorting Issue]

Comment: Can you check the inferred type of the `results` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue.. my array is realm object, so i used sorted function of realm.
Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 results.sort({  (e1:Event,e2:Event) -> Bool in
        return e1.checkInTime.compare(e2.checkInTime) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    })
```

Considering `Event` as your custom class